# Valgrind: The Impossible Happened IA-64 cached detected

Tags: c, debugging, x86-64, valgrind, itanium

I ran valgrind on a c program and got the following error:

```
valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   IA-64 cache detected?!

valgrind: m_threadstate.c:100 (vgPlain_get_ThreadState): Assertion 'tid >= 0 && tid < VG_N_THREADS' failed.
```

After fixing some memory leaks and restructure my program, the error mysteriously went away. But I searched online and find nothing about the IA-64 cache detected error. What does IA-64 means? Also, I ran the program on a virtual machine if that matters.

Comment: Are you running the code on an HP server?  They are one of the very few IA-64 machines around.  IA-64 means "Intel Architecture for 64-bits" or thereabouts.  It was intended to be the successor to the IA-32 architecture — represented by 80x86 processors.  However, the AMD x86/64 architecture proved to be more successful and IA-64 is in the last stages of dying (no new machines; no new o/s; I'm not sure whether there are even security updates any more).

Comment: IA-64 means Itanium and it's unlikely that you're using that architecture. [Valgrind also doesn't support Itanium](https://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html) so it's probably a wrong message

Comment: What CPU are you using?  I wonder if recent Intel or AMD x86-64 CPUs have repurposed the CPUID field value that IA-64 used to use, as Paul Floyd's answer mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, IA-64 is the Intel Architecture Itanium (actually a joint venture with HP). It dates back to the early 2000s. Support for the IA-64 architecture was never added to Valgrind since it was never a great success.

Earlier Itanium chips did have a kind of dual-mode which allowed them to run 32bit x86 code.

The error message in Valgrind comes from the `Intel_cache_info` function. This queries the `cpuid` instruction to find out about the cache. 10 of the codes handled by this function are for IA-64. As I said, this was never supported, so Valgrind terminates with a now rather dated message.

You are also getting an assert that the TID is not valid. So something is going seriously wrong.

If you can reproduce the problem with a small example then please report it on https://bugs.kde.org

Comment: I ran the code on Oracle VM Virtual machine with Ubuntu. My host computer is a Windows machine. My computer has an Intel chip i9-12900. When I set the max processor in the VM to 5, the error appears. However, when I set it to 6 the error disappear. Does this issue has something to do with the configuration of the VM?

Answer (score 0):

I was running my program on a 5 core VM. I switched to another VM that has 12 cores, and it worked. I still don't know what IA-64 cache means though.

Comment: That probably disguises the problem rather than solving it.  The number of cores shouldn't make a difference.